# Numpy/Scipy pinv and pinv2 behave differently

Tags: numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, matrix-inverse

I am working with bidimensional arrays on Numpy for Extreme Learning Machines. One of my arrays, H, is random, and I want to compute its pseudoinverse.
If I use scipy.linalg.pinv2 everything runs smoothly. However, if I use scipy.linalg.pinv, sometimes (30-40% of the times) problems arise.

The reason why I am using pinv2 is because I read (here: http://vene.ro/blog/inverses-pseudoinverses-numerical-issues-speed-symmetry.html ) that pinv2 performs better on "tall" and on "wide" arrays.

The problem is that, if H has a column j of all 1, pinv(H) has huge coefficients at row j.
This is in turn a problem because, in such cases, np.dot(pinv(H), Y) contains some nan values (Y is an array of small integers).

Now, I am not into linear algebra and numeric computation enough to understand if this is a bug or some precision related property of the two functions. I would like you to answer this question so that, if it's the case, I can file a bug report (honestly, at the moment I would not even know what to write).

I saved the arrays with np.savetxt(fn, a, '%.2e', ';'): please, see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48242012/example.tar.gz to find them.

Any help is appreciated. In the provided file, you can see in pinv(H).csv that rows 14, 33, 55, 56 and 99 have huge values, while in pinv2(H) the same rows have more decent values.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: switch to floats instead of integers?

Comment: Can you explain why would that change the result?

Comment: I haven't looked at yr data, but if you've got values >32-bit ints, you may be forcing data into NaN-land.

Comment: The different behaviour of pinv and pinv2 is before the NaNs appear. They appear in a successive dot product. You are right that at this point the dot between big some big ints and float16s could result in NaNs because the result array would still be float16 and hence unable to store big values. However, this does not explain why the results of pinv and pinv2 are so different.

Comment: As of 2022, `pinv2` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

In short, the two functions implement two different ways to calculate the pseudoinverse matrix:

1. scipy.linalg.pinv uses least squares, which may be quite compute intensive and take up a lot of memory.
   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.pinv.html#scipy.linalg.pinv
2. scipy.linalg.pinv2 uses SVD (singular value decomposition), which should run with a smaller memory footprint in most cases.
   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.pinv2.html#scipy.linalg.pinv2
   numpy.linalg.pinv also implements this method.

As these are two different evaluation methods, the resulting matrices will not be the same. Each method has its own advantages and disadvantages, and it is not always easy to determine which one should be used without deeply understanding the data and what the pseudoinverse will be used for. I'd simply suggest some trial-and-error and use the one which gives you the best results for your classifier.

Note that in some cases these functions cannot converge to a solution, and will then raise a scipy.stats.LinAlgError. In that case you may try to use the second pinv implementation, which will greatly reduce the amount of errors you receive.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from scipy 1.7.0 , `pinv2` is deprecated and also replaced by a SVD solution.

`DeprecationWarning: scipy.linalg.pinv2 is deprecated since SciPy 1.7.0, use scipy.linalg.pinv instead`

That means, `numpy.pinv`, `scipy.pinv` and `scipy.pinv2` now compute all equivalent solutions. They are also equally fast in their computation, with `scipy` being slightly faster.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

arr = np.random.rand(1000, 2000)
res1 = np.linalg.pinv(arr)
res2 = scipy.linalg.pinv(arr)
res3 = scipy.linalg.pinv2(arr)

np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(res1, res2, decimal=10)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(res1, res3, decimal=10)
```